# How to tell if PHP is outputting UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8

I have the following code to make PHP utf8 in my PHP file

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

I have the following in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I'm fetching a page using CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
```

This has some wierd characters, quotes and doublequotes are displayed as â

I found that this outputs the string correctly but html entities are shown as `?` marks.

```
utf8_decode($str);
```

This means my page is not actually outputting in utf8.. i'm using firefox, how can I fix this issue?! To make the page fully utf8 compatible (ideal), or to remove the html entities.

I've tried using to substitute prior to utf8_decode but it messes the output

```
$str = htmlentities($str,ENT_SUBSTITUTE,'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Note that utf8_decode is an extremely badly named function, which assumes the input string is UTF-8, and converts it as best as possible to the 8-bit encoding ISO8859-1, replacing anything not in that 1980s codepage with '?'. This is very rarely what you need, and certainly not a magic spell to make a page "UTF-8 compatible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in most cases the function `mb_detect_encoding($str)` will tell you what encoding your variable is.

you may also want to checkout the header

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

now in your curl request you are setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');` now valid options for this setting are the  "identity", "deflate" or "gzip", UTF-8 is not in the list, 
so remove that line, and then detect the encoding of what you receive then convert the encoding accordingly using a function such as `mb_convert_encoding()`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me find that the utf8 string was being appended to an ASCII string so the eventual output was ascii. I have converted it to utf8 but i find i still have to clean the original utf8 strnig the same way using utf8 decode. Nevertheless it works and the final output is utf8.